# Http/2 Pusher vs gRPC performance

Tags: grpc, http2

The requirement of my application is to send the data from the server to the client once the connection is established over HTTP/2.
I have opted to go with a combination of SSE for frontend and HTTP/2 Pusher in the backend.
But since gRPC is in general availability for the browser clients, I am thinking to switch to gRPC (because of simpler structure and protobufs) but I couldn't find any performance benchmarks for these two.
So whats better Http/2 with Pusher making a uni-directional channel or gRPC with a bi-directional channel.